# How to check length of list and length of each string in list to generate value using Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

i want to create resources in following names dev-db , stage-db and test-db

```
env_suffix = ["dev", "stage", "test"]

suffix = length(var.env_suffix) > 0 ? formatlist("%s-", var.env_suffix) : [""]
```

here in the above example based on the length of list the suffix is named like dev-db , stage-db and test-db if list is empty it ignores the suffix value. and just create db

now i want to add an empty string so based on the length of string it need to generate the value. so in addition to length of list i need to check length of each string to decide the value.

```
env_suffix = ["", "dev", "stage", "test"]

expected output  db, dev-db , stage-db and test-db
```

how should i format or add another loop where it check length of each item in list. so empty value in list will not add hypen and other suffix will add hyphen.

Any guidance or examples will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
envs = [for suffix in local.env_suffix: length(suffix) > 0 ? "${suffix}-db" : "db"]
```